# Custom Image Filter and multiple colored filter

Tags: ios, swift, ciimage

I'm trying to implement a filter like the LGBT color scheme (it a few stripes of color, one on top of the other) for an iOS app. Does anyone have any experience with this? I've been searching all over. I've created my app starting from Ray Wenderlich's tutorial(http://www.raywenderlich.com/76285/beginning-core-image-swift), but I see nothing about making custom Image Filters. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

We can't custom create filters in iOS.

> On OS X, if the filters provided by Core Image don’t provide the functionality you need, you can write your own filter. (Custom filters are not available on iOS.) You can include a filter as part of an application project, or you can package one or more filters as a standalone image unit. Image units use the NSBundle class and represent the plug-in architecture for filters.

Here is the apple doc
[Creating Custom Filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH6-TPXREF101)

And someone else has already talk about this issue, see

[how-to-create-simple-custom-filter-for-ios-using-core-image-framework](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895905/how-to-create-simple-custom-filter-for-ios-using-core-image-framework)