# How to apply Cool and warm tone CIFilter in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

I am working on `Video` based `Application` in `Swift iOS`. Where I am using `AVPlayer` to play the `Video` and setting `CIFilters` on `Video` using `AVVideoComposition`. I have to apply `Cool and warm tone filter effects` on my `Videos` (please see the below images).

[image]

[image]

I have tried all the `Core Image Filters` mentioned in below `Apple doc`, but none of them looks like `Cool and warm tone filter effect`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html

Can anyone have worked on the same? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @Frank Schlegel for direct me to `CITemperatureAndTint` Filter with `inputNeutral` and `inputTargetNeutral`. Please see the below Core Image Filter Parameter to get Warm and Cold tone effect :

```
filter = CIFilter(name: "CITemperatureAndTint")!
```

//cold

```
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 16000, y: 1000), forKey: "inputNeutral")
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 1000, y: 500), forKey: "inputTargetNeutral")
```

//warm

```
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 6500, y: 500), forKey: "inputNeutral")
filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 1000, y: 630), forKey: "inputTargetNeutral")
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the [`CITemperatureAndTint` filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CITemperatureAndTint) is what you are looking for. I frankly don't know exactly how the parameters work, but maybe you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464266/citemperatureandtint-for-image-in-ios) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999571/whats-up-with-citemperatureandtint-having-vector-inputs) related question.

Comment: Thanks @Frank Schlegel for your response, I tried using CITemperatureAndTint filter but no difference in preview. Looks similar to original video :(

Comment: Did you play around with the `inputNeutral` and `inputTargetNeutral` parameters?

Comment: No I don't. Can you help me on the same?

Comment: As I understood it, `inputNeutral` defines the color temperate and tint of the reference point, and `inputTargetNeutral` the same for the target point. So maybe pick some reference point in the middle (or keep the default of 6500K) and move the taget to warmer or colder colors (like 1000K).

Comment: Maybe try this for a start: `[filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:1000 Y:0] forKey:@"inputTargetNeutral"];`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Frank Schlegel for directing me to CITemperatureAndTint Filter. I can able to get Warm by setting filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 1000, y: 0), forKey: "inputNeutral")
                filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 1000, y: 0), forKey: "inputTargetNeutral"). But can you help me to get parameters for Cool?

Comment: Check out the color temperature map from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature. Values around 12000K should yield nice cold colors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190088/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-frank-schlegel).